# Array of colors in python

Tags: python

What's the quickest way to get an array of colors in python? Something I can index and pass to as the "color=" argument plotting in pylab.

The best I can come up with is:

```
colors = [(random(),random(),random()) for i in range(10)]
```

but a solution that can generate well-spaced colors (interpolated?) would be preferable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
from random import randint
colors = []

for i in range(10):
    colors.append('#%06X' % randint(0, 0xFFFFFF))
```

### Result Example:

`['#37AB65', '#3DF735', '#AD6D70', '#EC2504', '#8C0B90', '#C0E4FF', '#27B502', '#7C60A8', '#CF95D7', '#145JKH']`

*ps: thanks to @Inerdia*

Comment: That drops leading 0s, like in  `'#C56C3'`

Comment: Did not notice, fixed accordingly. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: You could replace all of getrandhex() and the string format with `'#%06X' % randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)`

Comment: Didn't know that python has string substition for hex =) Cool.

Comment: this work only if you add #
like this: colors.append('#%06X' % randint(0, 0xFFFFFF))

Answer (score 4):

It seems like matplotlib comes with several builtin "colormaps". You can get one using [get_cmap()](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.get_cmap).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply make a list or a dictionary and add the colors to it, I don't know how pylab works but I found an example which might work for you [here](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Matplotlib/Show_colormaps).

```
from pylab import *
cdict = {'red': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                 (0.5, 1.0, 0.7),
                 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
         'green': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                   (0.5, 1.0, 0.0),
                   (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
         'blue': ((0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  (0.5, 1.0, 0.0),
                  (1.0, 0.5, 1.0))}
my_cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_colormap',cdict,256)
pcolor(rand(10,10),cmap=my_cmap)
colorbar()
```

Comment: Does that give an array I can simply index?

Comment: @pufferfish A colormap is a thing that maps numbers from 0 to 1 to colors. If you can't index it directly the way you want it should be easy enough to just sample colors from one.

Comment: @pufferfish You can type `cdict['red']` to get the values of red. If this is how pylab works, I'm not sure.
However, you can use that as an example to put your own values if you want to. Another way is: `colors = []` and then `colors.append("value")`.