# Python: how to get a list of n different colors from a colormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I would like to get a list of `n` different colors from a colormap.

Let say we have to plot `n=3` lines

```
plt.plot(x0,y0, color=color[0])
plt.plot(x1,y1, color=color[1])
plt.plot(x2,y2, color=color[2])
```

Is it possible to get a the list `color` from a colormap?

Comment: Please take a look to [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html)

Comment: See in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33905962/4124317) in the dupe.

Answer (score 6):

RGB colors can be created randomly, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7827704/7041244) post.

```
from random import randint
color = []
n = 3
for i in range(n):
    color.append('#%06X' % randint(0, 0xFFFFFF))
```

Output

> ['#C0055C', '#22F2C4', '#8A890E']

Now, these can be used as colors im plot simply by

```
plt.scatter(0,0, color=color[0])
plt.scatter(1,1, color=color[1])
plt.scatter(2,2, color=color[2])
plt.legend(['p1', 'p2', 'p3'])
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: as a oneliner: `color = ['#%06X' % randint(0, 0xFFFFFF) for _ in range(n)]`